# How to convert JSON date to the a special format in Python?

Tags: python, json, datetime, data-conversion

I am parsing a JSON file in Python 2.7 that includes

```
"TimestampUtc":"\/Date(1477393888000)\/
```

and I want to parse this file and convert the date into :

```
8:11 a.m. Oct. 25, 2016
```

The original time zone is in the US and I want to get exactly the same output.
But this format is not that common and other similar questions don't answer it. Is there any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Converting ASP.Net JSON Date into Python datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039625/converting-asp-net-json-date-into-python-datetime)

Comment: The out put that I asked for is different from the above questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = "1467717221000"
>>> d = int(d[:10])
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
'2016-07-05 04:43:41 PM'
```

edit:
Format update :

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime(' %I:%M %p %b. %d, %y').replace("PM","p.m.").replace("AM","a.m.")
' 04:43 p.m. 07. 05, 16'
```

Comment: @ Harsha Biyani : Thank you, the output has to be like "9:19 a.m. Oct. 28, 2016".

Comment: at lest that you can change the format by modifying the sequence.

Comment: All answers pint out the same date as out put, but in the website that I am working on , it's "9:19 a.m. Oct. 28, 2016" and not " 04:43 p.m. 07. 05, 16". It's strange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I executed your code for "TimestampUtc = "\/Date(1477657148000)\/" and the output is " 02:19 p.m. Oct. 28, 16", but it must be "9:19 a.m. Oct. 28, 2016". The difference is marginal but it is not exactly same :(

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
import datetime
import re


TimestampUtc = "\/Date(1467717221000)\/"

TimestampUtc = re.split('\(|\)', TimestampUtc)[1][:10]
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(TimestampUtc))
print date
print date.strftime('%I:%M %p %b. %d, %Y')
print date.strftime('%I:%M %p %b. %d, %Y').replace('AM', 'a.m.').replace('PM', 'p.m.')
```

Output:

```
2016-07-05 19:13:41
07:13 PM Jul. 05, 2016
07:13 p.m. Jul. 05, 2016
```

Comment: @ kissbug: thank you so much, it's the closest answer to my question, just one question, The output has to be "9:19 a.m. Oct. 28, 2016" but in your code it's different. Also, I want to have 9 instead of 09. How I can do it?

Comment: [http://strftime.org/](http://strftime.org/) is the format of the **strftime**, and You can use **%-I** instead **%I**,  different time zone run the code will get the different local time

Comment: I executed your code for "TimestampUtc = "\/Date(1477657148000)\/" and the output is "02:19 PM Oct. 28, 2016", but it must be "9:19 a.m. Oct. 28, 2016". The difference is marginal but it is not exactly same

Comment: It's so interesting , I am getting this times from a website from the US, how I can exactly extract the same times in that website? Also adding %-I in python 2.7 gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the unit of your timestamp is milli seconds. 
So divide it into 1000 then you get `1467717221`. And using date time module for get the time. Then convert it to your format by `strftime`.

```
from datetime import datetime

newTimeString = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1467717221).strftime('%I:%M %p %b. %d, %Y')
```

you can find formatting from here(https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @ Hulk: thank you , I tried this one, the correct output is "9:19 a.m. Oct. 28, 2016" but under your code it is : "11:13 AM Jul. 05, 2016"